# React custom hooks how to return a callback function to parent

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have this custom hook for pagination and i want to fire SetLoadMore function in parent class what is the way to do it?

**Paging** is a returned value

**handleListEnd SetFetchMore** are functions from parent

but how to pass a function from hook to parent

**Please note: i don't want to use useEffect in parent() to check for value difference**

```
  const usePaging=(SubStories)=>{
    
      const [FetchMore,SetFetchMore]=React.useState(false)
    
      const [Paging,SetPaging]=React.useState(0)
      const handleListEnd=()=>{
      if(SubStories.length > 0 && !FetchMore){
      SetFetchMore(true)
    
        console.log("Data")
        SetPaging(SubStories.length)
      }
      }
    
      React.useEffect(()=>{
        if(Paging > 0){
          setTimeout(()=>{
    
    //how to pass the to parent function 
SetLoadMore()
           }, 300);
    
        }
      },[Paging])
      
    return [Paging,handleListEnd,SetFetchMore,SetLoadMore]
    }
```

This is the parent function

```
    function ParentFunction(){
    const [Paging,handleListEnd,SetFetchMore,SetLoadMore] =usePaging(DataArraty)
    /*

something like
const [Paging,handleListEnd,SetFetchMore,()=>{

//fire function
}] =usePaging(DataArraty)
*/
    return null
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass SetLoadMore as second argument of usePaging

```
const usePaging=(SubStories, setLoadMore)=>{
  // ...
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    if(Paging > 0){
      setTimeout(()=>{
        setLoadMore();
      }, 300);
    }
 }, [Paging, setLoadMore])
}

function ParentFunction(){
  const [Paging,handleListEnd,SetFetchMore] =usePaging(DataArraty, () => {
    // .. do something
  })
}
```

Comment: Why didn't i think of that ,thank you!!